# Reference between classes in C#?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm taking an introduction course in databases, and am working on the first hand-in.
One of the questions is to "add a reference in the class User so it can acces a users Organization"
I have a User class that looks like this:

```
 public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
```

And my organization class looks like this:

```
public class Organization
    {
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't understand the question stated by my teacher -- what does it mean to add a reference, when both classes are declared in the same .cs file?

Comment: This is an entity framework question?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should have specified.

Comment: Code first or database first? This needs a lot more context

Comment: Whether or not classes are defined in the same .cs file doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, code first

Comment: if you are using EF-Core [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: the purpose of a teacher is to explain everything that is unclear. As such, the best idea is to ask him to clarify what he means instead of coming to SO for this.

Comment: Do you know if it is a one-to-many or one-to-one relationship you want? (User can have one or many organizations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question refers to foreign key. It is something like "User is part of Organization".

Example:

```
 public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Standard
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Please refer to the following page for more information about foreign key in Entity framework:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't the `Students` collection be marked as `virtual`?

Comment: @GWigWam yes if you want to enable the lazy loading functionality of EF.